# Android Studio not able to recognize my music files?

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm attempting to implement music and sound effects into an application. The music files are all `.ogg`, but when I try to add them to `/res` folder, instead of getting a music file, I get an error that reads "File was loaded with wrong encoding: UTF-8", and a text file filled with what seems to be Unicode:

```
ggS         'et    b��,vorbis    D�       }      �OggS          'et   ��-�������������5vorbis   Xiph.Org libVorbis I 20050304    vorbisBCV   cV)f�R�[�s�1gc�Z�%�B(�sV[�)��ZʹŜsΕbR)E�RP[�cR)S[i!�B�s[i���Zj9��s��RN)�S�J�RL)�S�J�s�9�S�J5�ZS�1��[K)tNB���RK�t�J%tP:k9�S)�cVBj��Sʭ��s��АU   �@�
 P  ��(���� 2  �(��(�"9�c9�
     �pI���M�,��<S�eY�eY�eY�]�u] 4d   @(����
Y     �(�BCV   Q!档�{�r!���{�!�^9ꡤ�{��{���{�a^!硓�{�břr�{�!��1蝃�{���s�9��{�A���{^1靣^{�%�Bꥤ�{���{���{���{���{���j���{���{���{���{���{�АU    a6�qǤ��{a�'�i���{�gz
���{���{���{ 4d    !�RH!�RH!�b�!��*����*����*�,��2�(��2�,��:���B
)��J��T[o-��B!�B!���
```

Not sure what's going on, I thought it was as simple as moving music files to the Android Studio `res` folder?

Edit: I created a `raw` folder under `res` and moved the `.ogg` file there.

[image: raw-folder]

However, I got the same result shown above. Could it be that Android Studios doesn't recognize `.ogg` file format?

Answer (score 0):

Create a `raw` folder under `res` and add them there. Like this:

[image: raw folder under res]